# Why does swiftUI give me errors for correct code?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

SwiftUI has been giving me errors and refusing to build when I know that the code is correct. For instance the following code was working all of 15 minutes ago. I tried to wrap the `List` in `JumpToBookView` in a `VStack` and add a `Button` underneath the list, and it started spitting out errors on my `Image` in `BookRow`. This code was compiling and showing in the preview before I added the `Button` and `VStack`, after I removed them, it still won't let me preview the view. I have tried cleaning the build folder, deleting derived data, and quitting the application, all at the same time, and still nothing. No preview, and the project won't compile. For background, the project is mainly UIKit, but I'm trying to incorporate SwiftUI into it, even though that shouldn't matter because this view is not called anywhere. I am currently running the latest version of Xcode, and have attached my code and a screenshot of the errors. For search, I will also paste the errors here. `Missing argument label 'imageName:' in call`, `Value of type 'Image' has no member 'resizable'`, and `Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'fit'`

[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct JumpToBookView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            BookRow(selected: true)
            BookRow(selected: true)
            BookRow(selected: true)
            BookRow(selected: true)
            BookRow(selected: true)
            BookRow(selected: true)
        }
    }
    
    func testJump()
    {
        print("test")
    }
}

struct BookRow: View {
    var selected: Bool
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color(RaiseColor.red))
            HStack{
                Text("1.2 What is an Ecosystem?")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.white))
                Spacer()
                Image(selected ? "pauseButton" : "playButton")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(maxWidth: 25)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.white))
            }
            .padding(.all)
        }
    }
}


struct JumpToBookView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        JumpToBookView()
    }
}
```

EDIT: I just want to add that it was also working with `RaiseColor.red` before, so there shouldn't be any issues with that custom color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue ended up being that my codebase had previously defined a class named `Image`, so SwiftUI was having issues figuring out which `Image` I was trying to reference. Without making other changes to the codebase, this issue was resolved by specifying SwiftUI as the parent of `Image`, which can be done by the following `SwiftUI.Image(selected ? "pauseButton" : "playButton")"`. This fixes all of the issues I was having, but the best thing to do would be to refactor your codebase in order to not have conflicting names with SwiftUI classes and structs.

Answer (score 0):

When I replace this

> ```
> Rectangle()
>     .fill(Color(RaiseColor.red))
> ```

with this

```
Rectangle()
    .fill(Color.red)
```

all compiled well... so look for error in that custom color.

Comment: I tried to swap that out, but am still getting the errors. I also should add that it was working and previewing with the custom color `RaiseColor.red`

Comment: Is `RaiseColor.red` a UIColor?

Comment: Yes it is, but even if I take out the image and leave the color I get no errors. Something strange I just noticed is that the preview will still live update if a change is made, for instance if I add a text the the HStack, and it'll show up in the preview, the errors remain, and I cannot compile without it failing.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that i named an intentdefinition enum to Color. I renamed it and it's working fine again.